# Laravel - using mysql functions on where clause colmn

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a database with encrypted field using AES_ENCRYPT

the data is encrypted and should stay this way, so there is no way of changing the method it is encrypted with.

Recently I started working on a new project with Laravel.
when I tried to do an update with a where clause on the field encrypted with AES,
I received the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `mail` = ? LIMIT 1
```

And the following binding:

```
AES_ENCRYPT('email@email.com', 'somekey')
```

For the following code:

```
$email = Input::get('email');
$user = User::where("mail", "AES_ENCRYPT('{$email}', '{$this->aesKey}')")->first();
```

Which is basically logical - But how do I use force it do the following Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `mail` = AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'someKey') limit 1
```

With this binding:

```
email@email.com
```

Hope there is a way passing function to the where clause on the value

Comment: This don't answer to your question so I post as a comment, but you could crypt the password BEFORE sending the query to mysql with Laravel Crypter::encrypt(); (Need MCrypt php extension)

http://codehappy.daylerees.com/encryption

Key must be set in (app/config/app.php)

Comment: As i said - the data is already encrypted in aes. Crypter adds salt to the encryption so the result is not as stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In laravel 5 you can use whereRaw with bindings too, so you get correct escaping and injection prevention.

Just pass bindings array as second parameter.
For example:

```
$user = User::where("mail = AES_ENCRYPT(:email, :aesKey)", ['email' => $email, 'aesKey' => $this->aesKey])->first();
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try with [whereRaw()](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Query.Builder.html#_whereRaw)

```
$user = User::whereRaw("mail", "AES_ENCRYPT('{$email}', '{$this->aesKey}')")->first();
```

Or just with a RAW expression:

```
$user = User::where("mail", DB::raw("AES_ENCRYPT('{$email}', '{$this->aesKey}'))")->first();
```

Comment: WhereRaw() don't work because it tries to use the "raw" column which doesn't exists. even if you will try whereMail('AES_ENCRYPT(...)') it will try to use the value as a string and not as a function.

But! The second answer worked very well =]

Comment: I never used whereRaw() to be honest (for this kind of queries I always use `raw()`), but I was browsing the API and saw that method, I thought it could have worked too. But glad your problem is solved!

Comment: whereRaw does work, it just has a different syntax from the usual where method. You pass the full sql string, not split into column/value :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = User::whereRaw("mail = AES_ENCRYPT('{$email}', '{$this->aesKey}')")->first();
```

Comment: I tried this method and also works great. I think this is a more clean way to do this, you don't have to nest classes, and you can use a built in function for this. Much better solution I think